# How do I add to some date excluding weekends using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, date

For example:

```
@dtBegin = '2012-06-29' 

@input = 20
```

I want the output to be `'2012-07-27'`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add business days to date in SQL without loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471524/add-business-days-to-date-in-sql-without-loops)

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471524/add-business-days-to-date-in-sql-without-loops). **Edit:** I'm pretty sure that question answers this one exactly.

Comment: Have you seen this ? [Using Dateadd() to ignore weekends](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/transactsql/thread/63e15c8c-8dc1-4fff-8666-b850c7216db6) : **MSDN Article**

Answer (score 1):

I had to tackle the same problem in my project. Gordon Lionoff's solution got me on the right track but **did not always produce the right result**. I also have to take in account dates that start in a weekend. I.e. adding 1 business day to a saturday or sunday should result in a monday. This is the most common approach to handling [business day calculation](http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/time/date-day.php).

I've created my own solution based on Gordon Linoff's function and [Patrick McDonald's excellent C# equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044688/add-business-days-and-getbusinessdays)

**NOTE: My solution only works if DATEFIRST is set to the default value of 7**. If you use a different DATEFIRST value, you will have to change the `1`, `7` and `(1,7,8,9,10)` bits.

My solution consists of two functions. An "outer" function that handles edge cases and an "inner" function that performs the actual calculation. Both functions are table-valued functions so they will actually be expanded into the implementing query and fed through the query optimizer.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[UTL_DateAddWorkingDays]
(   
    @date datetime,
    @days int
)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN 
(
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN @days = 0 THEN @date
            WHEN DATEPART(dw, @date) = 1 THEN (SELECT Date FROM [dbo].[UTL_DateAddWorkingDays_Inner](DATEADD(d, 1, @date), @days - 1))
            WHEN DATEPART(dw, @date) = 7 THEN (SELECT Date FROM [dbo].[UTL_DateAddWorkingDays_Inner](DATEADD(d, 2, @date), @days - 1))
            ELSE (SELECT Date FROM [dbo].[UTL_DateAddWorkingDays_Inner](@date, @days))
        END AS Date
)
```

As you can see, the "outer" function handles:

- When adding no days, return the original date. This will keep saturday and sunday dates intact.
- When adding days to a sunday, start counting from monday. This consumes 1 day.
- When adding days to a saturday, start counting from monday. This consumes 1 day.
- In all other cases, perform the usual calculation

_

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[UTL_DateAddWorkingDays_Inner]
(   
    @date datetime,
    @days int
)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN 
(
    SELECT 
        DATEADD(d
        , (@days / 5) * 7 
          + (@days % 5) 
          + (CASE WHEN ((@days%5) + DATEPART(dw, @date)) IN (1,7,8,9,10) THEN 2 ELSE 0 END)
        , @date) AS Date
)
```

The "inner" function is similar to Gordon Linoff's solution, except it accounts for dates crossing weekend boundaries but without crossing a full week boundary.

Finally, I created a [test script](http://pastebin.com/NfMuFtdQ) to test my function. The expected values were generated using [Patrick McDonald's excellent C# equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044688/add-business-days-and-getbusinessdays) and I randomly cross-referenced this data with [this popular calculator](http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/time/date-day.php).

Comment: Performance with functions can be slow so watch out since you've got those nested calls in there. Do you really need a table function?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without resorting to a calendar table or user defined function:

```
dateadd(d,
        (@input / 5) * 7 + -- get complete weeks out of the way
        mod(@input, 5) + -- extra days
        (case when ((@input%5) + datepart(dw, @dtbegin)%7) in (7, 1, 8) or
                   ((@input%5) + datepart(dw, @dtbegin)%7) < (@input%5)
              then 2
              else 0
         end),
        @dtbegin
       )
```

I'm not saying this is pretty.  But sometimes arithmetic is preferable to a join or a loop.

Comment: Possible candidate for a UDF, then; `addWeekdays` or somesuch.

Comment: This solution produces incorrect results: I.e. Adding 3 days to thursday 20 september 2012 should produce wednesday 26 september 2012. However, this function produces monday 24 september 2012.

Comment: Untested, but this might work in place of the `case` expression if you like obfuscation! `abs(ceiling(@input%5 + datepart(dw, @dtbegin)%7 - 3) / 3 * 3 / 2.0))`

Comment: I wouldn't attempt datetime arithmetics. It's too easy to mess it up

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've tried:

```
CREATE function [dbo].[DateAddWorkDay]
(@days int,@FromDate Date)
returns Date
as
begin
declare @result date
set @result = (
select b
from
(
    SELECT
    b,
       (DATEDIFF(dd, a, b))
      -(DATEDIFF(wk, a, b) * 2)
      -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, a) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, b) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      -COUNT(o.Holiday_Date) 
      as workday
    from
    (
    select 
    @FromDate as a,
    dateadd(DAY,num +@days,@FromDate) as b
    from (select row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as num
          from Information_Schema.columns
         ) t
    where num <= 100 
    ) dt
    left join Holiday o on o.Holiday_Date between a and b and DATENAME(dw, o.Holiday_Date) not in('Saturday','Sunday') 
    where DATENAME(dw, b) not in('Saturday','Sunday')
          and b not in (select Holiday_Date from OP_Holiday where Holiday_Date between a and b) 

    group by a,b
) du
where workday =@days 

)
return @result 
end
```

Where `Holiday` is a table with `holiday_date` as a reference for holiday.

Answer (score 0):

I realize I'm about 8 years late to this party... But I took [Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12515831/1565706) and updated it to:

**1. a single scalar function instead of 2 nested table-valued functions**

I tested using his original test script and my function passes too. Also, it seems the rebuild to a scalar function has a slight *positive* impact on performance. Both versions seem to benefit equally from 'buffer caching', the scalar version performing up to 25% better non-cached and up to 40% better cached. *Disclaimer: I just ran both versions a bunch of times and recorded the times, I did not do any decent performance testing.*

**2. include support for DATEFIRST is either Monday, Saturday or Sunday**

I feel a UDF should be agnostic to the `datefirst` setting. I'm in Europe and Monday is the default here. The original function would not work without adaptation.

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week) Monday, Saturday and Sunday are the only real world first days of the week. Support for other could easily be added, but would make the code more bulky and I have a hard time envisioning a real world use case.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_addWorkDays
(   
    @date datetime,
    @days int
)
RETURNS DATETIME 
AS
BEGIN
    
    IF NOT @@DATEFIRST IN (1,6,7) BEGIN --UNSUPPORTED DATE FIRST
        RETURN NULL
    /* MONDAY = FRIST DAY */
    END ELSE IF @days = 0 BEGIN 
        RETURN @date
    END ELSE IF @@DATEFIRST = 1 AND DATEPART(dw, @date) = 7 BEGIN --SUNDAY
        SET @date = DATEADD(d, 1, @date)
        SET @days = @days - 1
    END ELSE IF @@DATEFIRST = 1 AND DATEPART(dw, @date) = 6 BEGIN --SATURDAY
        SET @date = DATEADD(d, 2, @date)
        SET @days = @days - 1

    /* SATURDAY = FRIST DAY */
    END ELSE IF @@DATEFIRST = 7 AND DATEPART(dw, @date) = 2 BEGIN --SUNDAY
        SET @date = DATEADD(d, 1, @date)
        SET @days = @days - 1
    END ELSE IF @@DATEFIRST = 7 AND DATEPART(dw, @date) = 1 BEGIN --SATURDAY
        SET @date = DATEADD(d, 2, @date)
        SET @days = @days - 1

    /* SUNDAY = FRIST DAY */
    END ELSE IF @@DATEFIRST = 7 AND DATEPART(dw, @date) = 1 BEGIN --SUNDAY
        SET @date = DATEADD(d, 1, @date)
        SET @days = @days - 1
    END ELSE IF @@DATEFIRST = 7 AND DATEPART(dw, @date) = 7 BEGIN --SATURDAY
        SET @date = DATEADD(d, 2, @date)
        SET @days = @days - 1

    END 

    DECLARE @return AS dateTime
    
    SELECT @return  =
        DATEADD(d
        , (@days / 5) * 7
          + (@days % 5)
          + (CASE 
                /* MONDAY = FRIST DAY */
                WHEN @@DATEFIRST = 1 AND ((@days%5) + DATEPART(dw, @date)) IN (6,7,8,9) THEN 2 
                /* SATURDAY = FRIST DAY */
                WHEN @@DATEFIRST = 7 AND ((@days%5) + DATEPART(dw, @date)) IN (1,2,8,9,10) THEN 2 
                /* SUNDAY = FRIST DAY */
                WHEN @@DATEFIRST = 7 AND ((@days%5) + DATEPART(dw, @date)) IN (1,7,8,9,10,11) THEN 2 
                ELSE 0 
            END)
        , @date) 

    RETURN @return 
END
```

I hope this might benefit someone!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below mentioned code for exclude weekends

```
go
if object_id('UTL_DateAddWorkingDays') is not null
drop function UTL_DateAddWorkingDays
go
create FUNCTION [dbo].[UTL_DateAddWorkingDays]
(   
    @date datetime,
    @daysToAdd int
)
RETURNS date
as
begin
declare @daysToAddCnt int=0,
@Dt datetime
declare @OutTable table
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    WeekDate date,
    DayId int
)
while @daysToAdd>0
begin
set @Dt=dateadd(day,@daysToAddCnt,@date)
--select @daysToAddCnt cnt,@Dt date,DATEPART(weekday,@Dt) dayId,@daysToAdd daystoAdd
    if(DATEPART(weekday,@Dt) <>7 and DATEPART(weekday,@Dt)<>1)
    begin
    insert into @outTable (WeekDate,DayId)
    select @Dt,DATEPART(weekday,DATEADD(day,@daysToAddCnt,@Dt))
    set @daysToAdd=@daysToAdd-1
    end
    set @daysToAddCnt=@daysToAddCnt+1

end
select @Dt=max(WeekDate) from @outTable
return @Dt
end
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

```
declare @d1 date='2012-06-29'
declare @days int=20

select dateadd(dd,@days,@d1)

select dateadd(dd,case DATEPART(dw,t1.d) when 6 then +2 when 7 then +1 else +0 end,t1.d)
from
(
    select dateadd(dd,CEILING((convert(float,@days)/5)*2)+@days,@d1)d
)t1
```

i found how many we in the range by `CEILING((convert(float,@days)/5)*2)`
then i added them to date and at the end i check if is a saturday or sunday and i add 1 or 2 days.