# db2 getting business dates between given dates

Tags: db2

I have a table called "Publicholidays" where in dates are stored as Varchar.
My query should fetch all values from say table xxxx between the user selected dates that exclude the weekends(sat,sun), public holidays. I am new to DB2 so can anyone suggest me ideas please
 Note: in DB dates are stored as String.

Comment: Do not store dates as strings. The `DATE` data type is there for a reason.

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?  [This is a solved problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471524/add-business-days-to-date-in-sql-without-loops) in a number of DBs (that question deals with SQL Server, but the answers should be convertible).  What does your date format look like?  Does your table include the weekends?  As others are pointing out, you really shouldn't be storing dates as strings, and having a calendar table will be a **huge** boon for this (and other queries).

Comment: Thanks.I have not designed this table and i need to do this implementation in the existing system.The date is stored as string in yyyy/mm/dd format. My publicholidays table doesn't have week ends. I have tried the below  SELECT * FROM SSLR204 WHERE CRDTR2 BETWEEN '2015/03/01' AND '2015/03/20' and CRDTR2  in ( select CRDTR2 from SSLR204 WHERE dayofweek(DATE(TO_DATE(CRDTR2, 'YYYY/MM/DD'))) not in(1,7 ) and CRDTR2 BETWEEN '2015/03/01' AND '2015/03/20')
and CRDTR2 NOT in (SELECT dates FROM PUBLICHOLIDAYS WHERE dates  BETWEEN '2015/03/01' AND '2015/03/31') is there anyway to optimize this?pl help

Answer (score 0):

Mistake #1 - Storing dates as strings.  Let's hope you have at least stored them YYYY-MM-DD and not MM-DD-YYYY.

Mistake #2 - Instead of a "Publicholidays" table, you need a Calendar (aka Dates or date conversion) table.  It should have a record for every day along with a few flag columns `BUSINESS_DAY`, `WEEKEND`, `PUBLIC_HOLIDAY`.  Alternatively, you could have a single `DAY_TYPE` column with values for business day, weekend and holiday.  You'll also want to have a `STRING_DATE` column to make conversion between your string date and a true date easier.

Google SQL Calender table and you'll find lots of examples and discussions.

Lastly, strongly consider fixing your DB to store dates in a date column.

Comment: Actually, I wouldn't store a string version in the DB (or at least not for "public" consumption), because formatting is culture and language dependent - information the DB is rarely told about at query time.  Formatting/parsing is a presentation-layer problem, and doesn't belong in the DB as such.  But oh yes, do you want a calendar table... index the sucker up, and you have one of the most versatile and useful aggregating tables possible.