# mysql adddate no weekends

Tags: mysql, date

first of all i know that this has been asked before, and there are some really good answers, but not 100% correct, since my reputation is low I can't post comments.
My question is how to add days in MySQL excluding weekends, for example
the day 1/8/2018 if we add 20 days the results should be 1/29/2018, most of the forum answers are like the following

SELECT `StartDate`,`Expected Date`,DATE_FORMAT( DATE_ADD(`StartDate`, INTERVAL `Expected Date` +

IF(
        (WEEK(`StartDate`) <> WEEK(DATE_ADD(`StartDate`, INTERVAL `Expected Date` DAY)))
        OR (WEEKDAY(DATE_ADD(`StartDate`, INTERVAL `Expected Date` DAY)) IN (5, 6)),
        IF(  `Expected Date` >0, 2, -2 ),
        0)
    DAY
    ) ,  '%y-%m-%d') as FinalDate from `table`,

THIS WORKS but for low numbers where it will encounter just one weekend, I do change the formula to accept minus add days. 
I know the tricky part is around IF(  `Expected Date` >0, 2, -2 ), where it add or delete more days if its weekend, but cant find a way to figure it out if there are more than 1 weekend in between.

i hope I make my self clear and some could help me.

Similar post but not 100% right
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38522170/mysql-add-working-days-to-date)

Thank you

Comment: Did you try the second answer?

Comment: yeah didnt work, but im testing it right now changing %v to %U, and will test it shortly with also minus days to add. Will be back soon with the results

Comment: works perfect with the %U, now if we try -5 days, we have an issue :), stil working/testing results

Comment: Well after many tests the positive work using the %U, BUT only if you want to add days. If you want to take out days no luck , even if  using DATE_SUB, if some one has a clue will be great. As  example please use the "start" date 2018-1-1