# SQL Changing Date by one workday and filter for it

Tags: sql, sql-server, filter, conditional-statements

I'm running the following query

```sql
    SELECT a.DAT
    FROM a
```

and getting a column of datetimes. I would like to change this column or alternatively add a column, that adds a workday to the corresponding datetime and I want to be able to filter for the date at the same time

My approach for changing the workday is like this `CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, date) = 'Friday' THEN DATEADD(dw, 3, date)`, but I don't know how to fit that in. Here I'm adding 3 days to Friday because it should skip to Monday the next workday, in the other cases I would add only 1 day, for Monday to Thursday.
Maybe there is a better way?

[image]

In this image I tried to show how the result of an examplatory query should
look like. I have all dates available but I want to filter for the 14th, which should show me the 11 dates, because of the added workday. Since June 11 is Friday

I think my Main problem is I don't know how make the extra column depending on the given datetime, it should add 3 on Fridays and 1 on every other day (Saturday and Sunday don't exist in the base data)

Thanks for your responses.

I have a solution now. If it can be easier, let me know, if you like. Anyway, thanks for your help everyone

Solution:

```sql
DECLARE @Date DATETIME
Set @Date = '14/06/2021'
SELECT
   a.DAT,
   (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, a.DAT) = 'Friday' THEN DATEADD(DAY, 3, a.DAT) ELSE DATEADD(DAY, 1, a.DAT) END) as RealDate
FROM a
WHERE (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @Date) = 'Monday' THEN DATEADD(DAY, -3, @Date) ELSE DATEADD(DAY, -1, @Date) END) = a.DAT
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MYSQL Add working days to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38522170/mysql-add-working-days-to-date)

Comment: Please dont add pictures to a post, but edit post with sample data output, also, why are you trying to  just add 3 days for a given column.  Why the filter for just the one day.  Edit your question and explain the WHY you care about the 3 days.  No context just on... here is a date column, add 3 days, but you are only showing data for 11th and 14th.

Comment: To help improve responses you should write the reason behind what you are trying to do. Are you just wanting to perform an SQL query for workdays? e.g. something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252519/count-work-days-between-two-dates

Datetime is an object which you can gather the information you need. It would be a poor schema design to have an additional column that has a corresponding day of the week.

Comment: Ok, but if i knew how i would have done that already^^. I want to search for a date (lets say June 14), but in my data everything for June 14 will be found only under June 11, but i cant know that in general since i dont want to look up every dates weekday. So the query must itself check how many days it needs to skip for my search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be describing a `case` expression:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday, date) = 'Friday'
             THEN DATEADD(DAY, 3, date)
             ELSE DATEADD(DAY, 1, date)
        END) as next_date
```

Comment: @autoque, and this skips over Sunday how when someone works on a weekend?

Comment: It doesnt, but that doesnt matter. As I said Saturdays do not appear in the main data.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to S/O.  If your table already has a datetime column, that is probably best.  Dont try to break things down such as a date column, a time column, and some workday column.  There are plenty of functions that allow you to extract parts as needed.  However, your post tags only show SQL instead of a specific database such as sql-server, mysql, oracle, etc. but appears SQL-Server via DateAdd() function.

With date functions you could do things like filtering based on the "Day" of the given date/time column NOT being a Sat or Sun.   Or, filtering on a single month by a >= first day of the month but less than first day of following month.  This way you dont have to worry about time factors.  This type of query would allow inclusion of working up to 11:59:59pm before following day.

If you edit your question with any additional clarifications on why adding 3 days per your example may help offer additional resolution.  Try not to just put things that could be long in comments.  Then just comment back on my post and I'll try to follow-up (in addition to others that may follow this post).

Comment: I have datetimes given. I dont want to break them apart, i want to know the next workday. The dateadd function was just an example how i change the date, i dont know another way. I have a problem with the syntax I cant fit filtering and the extra column at the same time