# SQL DATEADD(weekday, 1, date) does not seem to work?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, dateadd, weekday

Here is my query:

```
SELECT  ID AS 'securityid'
      , date
      , DATEADD(DW, 1, adate) AS 'lagged_date_v2'
      , DATEADD(DAY, 1, adate) AS 'lagged_date_v1'
      , aclose AS 'previous_close'
FROM    mytable
WHERE   adate BETWEEN '20170101 09:00' AND '20170630 18:00' AND
        ID = 100056;
```

Here are the output from the code above:

[image: Outputs image]

I compared the results to `DATEADD`by day and by weekday and it returns the same results.

Column `adate` is just typical date, we can tell `Jan 28, 2017` is Saturday. However, on this row, both `lagged_date_v1` and `lagged_date_v2` return `Jan 28`. If I use `DATEADD` by weekday correctly, I should see `Jan 30` instead `Jan 28`, right?

My sql server version is 2008.

Comment: "dayofyear, day, and weekday return the same value." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471524/add-business-days-to-date-in-sql-without-loops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I use DATEADD by weekday correctly, I should see Jan 30 instead Jan
>   28, right?

Wrong.  In SQL Server, `weekday` doesn't mean days that aren't weekend days.   It means which day of the week (1-7) is the day in question based on the current `datefirst` setting.

Comment: So wouldn't that be entirely redundant with `day`?

Comment: @TKK No, `day` is "day of the month" (eg 1st, 15th, 30th).  `weekday` is "day of the week" (eg:  Sunday, Wednesday, Friday).   Although for purposes of the first parameter of `DATEADD`, yes, they are the same.